# Merge two arrays with child elements

Tags: arrays, typescript

I've two arrays as follows and trying to merge with id in this case, menuNo is the id and after that, it'll have a new array with child elements as output. Parent menu with child menus.

**Array 1**:

```
[
  {
    "menuNo": "1001",
    "menuName": "All Forms",
    "groupNo": null,
    "groupName": null,
    "menuStatus": null,
    "groupStatus": null,
    "parentMenu": "0",
    "childMenu": null,
    "iconName": null
  },
  {
    "menuNo": "1003",
    "menuName": "All Forms 2",
    "groupNo": null,
    "groupName": null,
    "menuStatus": null,
    "groupStatus": null,
    "parentMenu": "0",
    "childMenu": null,
    "iconName": null
  },
  {
    "menuNo": "1006",
    "menuName": "All Forms 3",
    "groupNo": null,
    "groupName": null,
    "menuStatus": null,
    "groupStatus": null,
    "parentMenu": "0",
    "childMenu": null,
    "iconName": null
  }
]
```

**Array 2**:

```
[
  {
    "menuNo": "1002",
    "menuName": "Child 1",
    "groupNo": null,
    "groupName": null,
    "menuStatus": null,
    "groupStatus": null,
    "parentMenu": "1001",
    "childMenu": null,
    "iconName": null
  },
  {
    "menuNo": "1012",
    "menuName": "Child 2",
    "groupNo": null,
    "groupName": null,
    "menuStatus": null,
    "groupStatus": null,
    "parentMenu": "1001",
    "childMenu": null,
    "iconName": null
  },
  {
    "menuNo": "1014",
    "menuName": "Child 1",
    "groupNo": null,
    "groupName": null,
    "menuStatus": null,
    "groupStatus": null,
    "parentMenu": "1006",
    "childMenu": null,
    "iconName": null
  },
  {
    "menuNo": "1019",
    "menuName": "Child 2",
    "groupNo": null,
    "groupName": null,
    "menuStatus": null,
    "groupStatus": null,
    "parentMenu": "1006",
    "childMenu": null,
    "iconName": null
  },
]
```

**Expected Result in JSON**:

```
[{
  "menuNo": "1001",
  "menuName": "All Forms",
  "groupNo": null,
  "groupName": null,
  "menuStatus": null,
  "groupStatus": null,
  "parentMenu": "0",
  "childMenu": "Child 1", "Child 2",
  "iconName": null
},
{
  "menuNo": "1006",
  "menuName": "All Forms 3",
  "groupNo": null,
  "groupName": null,
  "menuStatus": null,
  "groupStatus": null,
  "parentMenu": "0",
  "childMenu": "Child 1", "Child 2"
  "iconName": null
}]
```

Tried this but it only merges all data on id as follows:

```js
//Merge two jSon object
const mergeById = (array1, array2) =>
    array1.map(itm => ({
      ...array2.find((item) => (item.id === itm.id) && item),
      ...itm
}));
```

My plan is to create a menu with a submenu as a list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need use `Array.filter` for `array2` based on `child.parentMenu === parent.menuNo`.
2. Next, filter `child` is not empty array nor `null`.

```js
const mergeById = (array1, array2) =>
array1.map(parent => ({
  ...parent,
  childMenu: array2.filter((child) => child && (child.parentMenu === parent.menuNo))
    .map(child => child && child.menuName)
}));

var result = mergeById(array1, array2)
  .filter(x => x.childMenu && x.childMenu.length > 0);
```

> Code snippet & Result

```js
var array1 = [
{
  "menuNo": "1001",
  "menuName": "All Forms",
  "groupNo": null,
  "groupName": null,
  "menuStatus": null,
  "groupStatus": null,
  "parentMenu": "0",
  "childMenu": null,
  "iconName": null
},
{
  "menuNo": "1003",
  "menuName": "All Forms 2",
  "groupNo": null,
  "groupName": null,
  "menuStatus": null,
  "groupStatus": null,
  "parentMenu": "0",
  "childMenu": null,
  "iconName": null
},
{
  "menuNo": "1006",
  "menuName": "All Forms 3",
  "groupNo": null,
  "groupName": null,
  "menuStatus": null,
  "groupStatus": null,
  "parentMenu": "0",
  "childMenu": null,
  "iconName": null
}
];

var array2 = [
{
  "menuNo": "1002",
  "menuName": "Child 1",
  "groupNo": null,
  "groupName": null,
  "menuStatus": null,
  "groupStatus": null,
  "parentMenu": "1001",
  "childMenu": null,
  "iconName": null
},
{
  "menuNo": "1012",
  "menuName": "Child 2",
  "groupNo": null,
  "groupName": null,
  "menuStatus": null,
  "groupStatus": null,
  "parentMenu": "1001",
  "childMenu": null,
  "iconName": null
},
{
  "menuNo": "1014",
  "menuName": "Child 1",
  "groupNo": null,
  "groupName": null,
  "menuStatus": null,
  "groupStatus": null,
  "parentMenu": "1006",
  "childMenu": null,
  "iconName": null
},
{
  "menuNo": "1019",
  "menuName": "Child 2",
  "groupNo": null,
  "groupName": null,
  "menuStatus": null,
  "groupStatus": null,
  "parentMenu": "1006",
  "childMenu": null,
  "iconName": null
}
];

const mergeById = (array1, array2) =>
array1.map(parent => ({
  ...parent,
  childMenu: array2.filter((child) => child && (child.parentMenu === parent.menuNo))
    .map(child => child && child.menuName)     
}));

var result = mergeById(array1, array2)
  .filter(x => x.childMenu && x.childMenu.length > 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: In some cases, child can be empty. I guess, the above should work.

Comment: Updated to `array2.filter((child) => child && (child.parentMenu === parent.menuNo))`.

Comment: Could you check the expected output in the post? It's updated, may be I wasn't clear enough. Yes, exactly.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, the `childMenu` have to be `"childMenu": ["Child 1", "Child 2"]`.

Comment: Done update answer, @user8512043

Comment: The above with example works but when I try to get the `jSon` data with a service, it shows blank in the result var. `parentMenus: any[];
  childMenus: any[]; menus: any[]; this.menuervice.getParentMenu().subscribe(result => {
      this.parentMenus = result;

      console.log(this.parentMenus);
    }, error => console.error(error));

    this.menuervice.getChildMenu().subscribe(result => {
      this.childMenus = result;

      console.log(this.childMenus);
    }, error => console.error(error));` In the console, it returns data perfectly but doesn't merge. Anything to do here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238798/discussion-between-yong-shun-and-user8512043).

Comment: Solved @Yong Shun - Thanks a lot.